# How to show precision in a confusion matrix

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix, precision-recall

I'm using scikit learn, and I want to show precision in the form of confusion matrix. So I have this confusion matrix:

```
array([[1266,   45,    6],
       [  25, 1507,   19],
       [  36,   82,  858]], dtype=int64)
```

And I applied this code, from another post here:

```
cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=1)[:, np.newaxis]
```

And the output was :

```
array([[0.96127563, 0.03416856, 0.00455581],
       [0.01611863, 0.97163121, 0.01225016],
       [0.03688525, 0.08401639, 0.87909836]])
```

However, this is the recall, not the precision. How can I make it show the precision?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found it, just change axis=0 instead of axis=1

```
cm = cm.astype('float') / cm.sum(axis=0)[:, np.newaxis]
```

okay, but there's a problem in this code, I have this output:

```
array([[0.954, 0.034, 0.005],
       [0.015, 0.922, 0.012],
       [0.041, 0.093, 0.972]])
```

And when you sum any row it should equal to 1, but it doesn't.

## Solved

Use this :

```
C / C.astype(np.float).sum(axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer for precision will be

```
import numpy as np
precision = np.diag(cm) / np.sum(cm, axis = 0)
```

Precision is `TP/(TP+FP)` hence the diagonal value which is the true positive and the sum of the column.

Update 1:
Based on your comment

```
precision = []
for x in np.nditer(cm):
    precision.append(x / np.sum(cm, axis = 0))
```

Comment: no, I wanted to be in the form of a matrix with normalized data, just like the recall matrix above

Comment: it's not working, it's giving me a long list :
[array([0.954, 0.775, 1.434]),
 array([0.034, 0.028, 0.051]),
 array([0.005, 0.004, 0.007]),
 array([0.019, 0.015, 0.028]),
 array([1.136, 0.922, 1.707]),
 array([0.014, 0.012, 0.022]),
 array([0.027, 0.022, 0.041]),
 array([0.062, 0.050, 0.093]),
 array([0.647, 0.525, 0.972])]

Comment: I tested the code on the sample matrix that you provided and i am getting correct output. I am not sure whats wrong on your side. Update your question with the matrix that you are feeding into my code so that I can replicate it.